# How to check all the columns are 0 in SQL Server without specifying all columns with OR condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to return an error flag when all columns are 0s in a temp table.

Is there any good method other than specifying all columns checking to 0 with OR condition?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your request well but you can simply check for Null.

Comment: I may have a solution for you but I need an example of your table with data

Comment: I guess checking if the total sum of the number columns (PK excluded) equals 0 isn't good enough?

Comment: That's what I would suggested

Comment: Can you still use the number fields in the query? Or are you looking for a dynamic sql that gets the field names from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql)

Comment: What do you mean "return an error flag"?

Answer (score 3):

An OUTER APPLY can be used to calculate the flag.

For example, from this sample data:

```
create table #test (
 id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
 col1 int not null, 
 col2 float, 
 col3 decimal(10,2)
);

insert into #test (col1, col2, col3) values
(1,0,0),(0,0.2,0),(0,null,0.3),(0,0,null),(0,0,0);
```

**This query:**

```
-- sum of nums check
select *
from #test t
outer apply (
    select cast(iif(sum(abs(v.num))>0,0,1) as bit) as AllZeroOrNullFlag
    from (values (col1),(col2),(col3)) v(num)
) ca
where ca.AllZeroOrNullFlag = 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
id  col1    col2    col3    AllZeroOrNullFlag
4   0       0       NULL    True
5   0       0       0,00    True
```

Answer (score 2):

Without more information at the moment, all I can suggest you is the following :

```
SELECT id, 'ERROR'
FROM temp
WHERE value1+value2+value3 = 0;
```

Assuming you can provide all numeric columns that you would have checked in OR condition. (EDIT: In fact it would have been AND condition instead of OR...)

[**SEE A DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6273/4)

Comment: `ABS(value1)` etc. (v1 = 1, v2 = -1 => sum 0)

Comment: You're completely right, this is assuming all values are positives or equals to 0. If not the use of ABS(value1)+ABS(value2)+ABS(value3) = 0 would be mandatory !

Comment: Jup, and probably an ISNULL for the nullables.

Comment: WHERE value1+value2+value3 = 0; solved my issue. Thanks.